# How can I clear an embedded matplotlib bar chart in tkinter?

Tags: python, debugging, canvas, matplotlib, tkinter

I do not understand which method I should be using in order to clear a matplotlib bar chart that I have embedded in my tkinter program.

Should I be focusing on getting rid of the canvas or should I be focused on using plt.cla or plt.clf(). I have tried both and as I am using Pycharm and the IDE doesn't show any other methods for me to use.

I will display my code below:

```
    def show_graph(self):

    self.infoLabel.config(text="")

    c.execute("SELECT * FROM " + self.trackName.get() + " WHERE Year_Of_Event = ? AND Athlete_Year_Group = ? "
                                                        "ORDER BY ATHLETE_TIME ASC", (self.eventYear.get(),
                                                                                      self.yearGroup.get()))
    self.athleteData = c.fetchall()

    if self.athleteData is None:
        self.infoLabel.configure(text="There are no records for the event in this year for this year group.")
    else:
        for self.item in self.athleteData:
            self.athlete = self.item
            self.x.append(self.athlete[1])
            self.truncatedTime = str(self.athlete[3]).replace((self.athlete[3])[5:], "")
            self.y.append(float(self.truncatedTime))
            self.text += (self.athlete[1]+" ran the "+self.trackName.get()+" in "+self.athlete[3]+" and is from the"
                          " house, "+self.athlete[4]+"\n")
            self.infoLabel.configure(text=self.text)

    self.numOfValues = len(self.x)
    self.ind = numpy.arange(self.numOfValues)

    self.colorChoice = random.choice(["r", "y", "b", "g", "w", "k", "m", "c"])
    self.rect = self.ax.bar(self.ind, self.y, width=self.width, color=self.colorChoice)

    # add some text for labels, title and axes ticks
    self.ax.set_ylabel('Time')
    self.ax.set_title('Times under which athletes ran a race.')
    self.ax.set_xticks(self.ind)
    self.ax.set_xticklabels(self.x)

    def label(bars):
        """
        Attach a text label in each bar displaying its height
        """
        for self.rect in bars:
            height = self.rect.get_height()
            self.ax.text(self.rect.get_x() + self.rect.get_width() / 2., 0.5 * height, int(height),
                         ha='center', va='bottom')

    label(self.rect)

    self.canvas.show()
    self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tkinter.BOTTOM, fill="x")

    self.canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=tkinter.BOTTOM, fill="x")

def clear_all(self):
    self.infoLabel.configure(text="")
```

I want to make it so that the clear_all function carries the code which clears the bar chart so I can plot different data on the chart.

I am not sure as to how I should go about this. Any help is very much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You may want to read [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

To clear graph you have to remove data from self.xList1 and self.yList1

```
self.xList1 = []
self.yList1 = []
```

because after clearing plot (`a.clear()/plt.clf()/plt.cla()`) you still have data in lists and you draw them again.

Comment: Thanks for your time but, upon trying that, the graph still plots data upon previous data. What I need is to be able to clear the plot. I have not used figure so that is why it is hard for me to use (a.clear()/plt.clf()/plt.cla()).